# Insert hashmap key and value in mybatis

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am simply trying to persist the map's key and value in a database using mybatis but I don't know how to fetch key and value from map in mybatis query

THIS IS MY QUERY:-

```
<insert id="insertCategory"
        parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
        INSERT
        <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index">
            INTO
            Category(Category_ID, Category_CODE, Category_Name)
            values(Category_SEQ,#{element.key},#{element.value})
        </foreach>
        SELECT * FROM dual
    </insert>
```

Comment: Instead of passing the map as param maybe you can pass the entry set and iterate it like a collection. Then you can access they key and value as #{entry.key} #{entry.value}

Comment: @Sanketh then what will be the parameterType in mybatis insert tag

Comment: Please add 1) the full stack trace if there is an error 2) what is in the map (e.g. String, Integer, POJO) and 3) the method signature if there is a mapper interface.

Comment: I want to know how to iterate entrySet of hashmap and fetch out key and value and persist in DB

Comment: @itiwarishubham I know. But to explain, I need those information (1, 2, 3) that I asked.